# Does any Latin noun originally end in -r?

Tags: language-evolution, consonants

Many Latin nouns end *-r*, like *honor*.
However, this word seems to have been originally *honos*, which became *honor-* in oblique cases due to rhotacism and the *-r* made its way to nominative by analogy.

The examples of final *-r* that I can think of either come from *-s* or are of an unclear origin to me.
Are there any Latin nouns with a final *-r* that does not come from rhotacism?
An example or two with a brief explanation of how we know that would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pater, mater, frater etc. are IE -r stems; compare pater with English father, Sanskrit (acc. s.) pitaram etc.

Iecur is an IE -r/n heteroclit, like Avestan yakarə.

Answer (score 3):

If we are to focus on very old formations, (Beekes 2011, 13.1.2) discusses substantive derivatives of PIE suffixes in *-r-*, which have indeed yielded many original Latin substantives in *-r*:

> We shall take the forms in *-r* and *-n* as examples to discuss.
>
> r-suffixes:
>   [1](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.252.9798&rep=rep1&type=pdf) ***-er-***‚ is used for the nominative of the neuter *r/n*-stems: ∗iekʷ-r ‘liver’; ∗h₁ésh₂-r ‘blood’: Skt. *ásr̥-k*, Hitt. *eshar*, Gr. *éar*. Adverbs in ***-er***: ∗(s)uper ‘above’: Skt. *upári*, Gr. *húper*, Lat. *super*.
>   [2] ***-ro-***‚ we find in a number of old words: ∗h₂eǵro-‚ ‘acre’; ∗uiHro-‚ ‘man’: Skt. *vīrá-*, Lith. *výras*, Lat. *vir*, OIr. *fer*, Goth. *wair* [...].
>   [3] ***-ro-***‚ also forms primary adjectives: ∗h₂ugró-‚ ‘strong’: Skt. *ugráâ-*; ∗h₁rudhró-‚ ‘red’.
>   [4] ***-ter-***‚ in words indicating kinship: ∗ph₂tá-r, and nomina agentis: ∗ǵenh₁-tōr ‘conceiver, father’: Skt. *janitár-*.
>   [5] ***-tro-***‚ is used for neuters which indicate the instrument: *h₂(e)rh₃trom ‘plough’: Gr. *árotron*.
>   [6] ***-tero-***: see the comparative[...]. Compare also *kʷoteros ‘who of two’

*(enumeration is mine -kkm)*. So this is a very good clue where to look for the substantives in Latin with the inherited *-r*. Under the same categories, the examples are:

1. Often body parts are in this inherited neuters category: *cor*, *venter*, *iecur*, *uber*, *uter*, *viscer*, *femur*; emotional states: *sopor*, *timor*, *torpor*, *pauor*, *moeror*; abstracts of quality *vigor*, *squalor*; names of perceptibles: aural *clamor*, *squalor*, *nurmur*, *fragor*, *fremor*, visual *nitor*, *fulgor*, olfactory *odor*, *fetor*, tactile *fervor*, *caldor*, *tepor*, *algor*.
2. Also *ager*, *arbor*. Seasons and parts of day: *ver*¹, *vesper*. There are very old tree names that probably belong to this category: *acer*, *robor*, etc. Meteorological: *fulgur*, *imber*.
3. *rubor*, *niger*, *ater*. There are many primary adjectives in *-r* in Latin in general, but the question, as I understand, is focused more on nouns.
4. *pater*, *mater*, *frater*²; cannot think of more. Both PIE and Latin are rich in kinship terms, but they did not end up ending in *-r* in Latin (as *sobrinus/sobrina* or *socrus*—although *∗socer* would not be unexpected here).
5. These mostly gave *-trum* in Latin. E. g... well, *computatrum*. :)
6. *uter*, *neuter*, and many comparatives (*citior, altior, fortior*... I shall stop here).

Also, there is an interesting [conference paper by Gorman](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.252.9798&rep=rep1&type=pdf)³ discussing how certain words managed to possibly escape the rhotic change.

---

Footnotes:
1. *ver* should have been etymologically **veror*, and might have undergone rhotacism before shortening.
2. *soror* and *uxor* are not in this category, but they do indeed end in *-r*, so why not mention them? Also, *mulier* does not belong also, because the stem would originally end in *s*, later lost. Not clear why it escaped rhotacism, as the loss should pre-date it. Let's just do not count it in.
3. The link is directly to paper, so in case it disappears, here's the cication: Gorman, Kyle. "Exceptions to rhotacism." Proceedings from the Annual Meeting of the Chicago Linguistic Society. Vol. 48. No. 1. Chicago Linguistic Society, 2012.

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never. For completeness I add here what I originally asked as a comment, and later researched.

Apparently there is this reconstructed PIE [*(é)-tōr](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-t%C5%8Dr) root, from which the [-tor, -toris](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-tor#Latin) agents and other words in Latin seem to derive, as well as Greek -τωρ and Sanskrit -tṛ suffixes.

This includes a [huge category of words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Latin_words_suffixed_with_-tor), including

> **factor, actor, lector, pictor, ianitor, dictator, salvator, sensor**, etc.