# How to find the stem of any word?

Tags: vocabulary, morphology, declension, conjugation

I am wondering if the stem of every word has an exact form?

For example:

- For the word `genus`, how could you determine is it `gen` or `gener`?
- For the word `līber`, how could you determine is it `līber` or `lībe`?
- For the word `videō`, how could you determine is it `vide` or `vidē`?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, there's no foolproof way to predict a noun stem from the nominative form.

Fortunately, you *can* predict the stem from the *genitive* form. So good Latin dictionaries will list both: your examples would be listed as *genus, generis* and *līber, līberī*.

The genitive endings are predictable, and also tell you which declension the noun belongs to: first will be *-ae*, second will be *-ī*, third will be *-is*, fourth will be *-ūs*, and fifth will be *-eī*.

So for a few examples:

- *servus, servī* (or *servus, -ī*) → *serv-*, second
- *corpus, corporis* (or *corpus, -oris*) → *corpor-*, third
- *tellūs, tellūris* → *tellūr-*, third
- *genus, generis* (or *genus, -eris*) → *gener-*, third
- *manus, manūs* (or *manus, -ūs*) → *man-*, fourth

The number of the declension is important to know, since it determines the endings.

Since you've added verbs, there's a trick to that too. Dictionaries will list both the citation form, *videō*, and the present active infinitive, *vidēre*. The latter is more informative on where the stem ends and the ending begins:

- *amō, amāre* (or *amō, -1*) → stem *amā-*
- *habeō, habēre* (or *habeō,-2*) → stem *habē-*
- *currō, currere* (or *currō, -3*) → stem *curr-*
- *faciō, facere* (or *faciō, -3*) → stem *fac-* with a couple special forms having an extra *-i-*
- *audiō, audīre* (or *audiō, -4*) → stem *audī-*

Here, knowing the specific conjugation number is less important for the present tense, since the endings are basically predictable—but it is important for the future!

Comment: yes, thanks, I have found the stem of the two nouns in your way.

Comment: Dictionaries may also indicate the conjugation using Roman or Arabic numerals. So *"nato I"* means that *nato* is of the first conjugation (which is the *a* conjugation, so the stem is *nata-*), whereas *"dico III"* means *dico* is of the third conjugation, the consontantal conjugation (so the stem is *dic-*). Further, when the infinitive is given, a macron on the ē may be used to indicate that is of the *e* conjugation, whereas no macron, or a breve, indicates a consonantal stem: *vidēre* (*e* stem, *vide-*), dicere or dicĕre (consontantal stem, *dic-*).

Comment: I think the term "stem" is usually used to refer to the combination of the root (for *servus,* *serv-*) and the theme vowel (which was reduced to *u* in the nominative singular, but which shows up as *ō* in the genitive plural).

Comment: @sumelic In a historical sense, that's absolutely right—but as traditionally taught, the stem is _serv-_ with the fossilized, un-analyzable endings _-us -ī -ō -um -ō -e_ etc attached to it. I'm guessing that's the meaning OP is asking for.

Comment: Can you add some citations about this being a traditional alternative definition of "stem"? I recall seeing references to that idea somewhere else, but the PIE-etymology-based definition of "stem" also seems to be quite old (I think it's been around for at least a century, and possibly two). Also, in a number of modern linguistic works about Latin and the Romance languages, the term "stem" seems to be used to refer to vowel-final morphological units as part of synchronic analyses of Latin or Romance morphophonology, not only in the context of historical linguistics.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you mean by "has an exact form". If you mean "has a single, invariant form", the answer would most likely be "no". According to several definitions of "stem", Latin words (including nouns) may have more than one stem (or alternatively, you could say that the stem of a word may have more than one form: it's a bit difficult to distinguish these two possibilities). The use of different stems for different forms of the word is called "heteroclisy".

### Different definitions of "stem"

The concept of a "stem" is not completely clear/unambiguous. I'm aware of at least three distinct definitions:

1. Etymological/historical linguistics/comparative IE linguistics: The stem of *līber* in a historical sense is *lībero-*; the nominative singular form is historically derived from *lībero-s* via syncope and loss of s after r (as explained in the "Type A." section of Alex B.'s answer to [Why do some 2nd decl. "-er" adjectives and nouns drop the "e" in the stem?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/377)).

   This word happens to be built on a single stem/single form in a historical sense, but that is not true for all words. IE "heteroclite" nouns existed; an example of a descendant in Latin is *iecur* "liver". This type of heteroclite noun is mentioned in the answers to [Does any Latin noun originally end in -r?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6661)
2. Synchronic analysis of Latin morphophonology according to certain modern linguistic theories: The stem of *līber* is a bit difficult to analyze; one option would be to treat this as a synchronically heteroclite adjective in Classical Latin, with the masculine nominative being built on a consonant-final stem *līber-* and the other masculine forms being built on a vowel-final stem *lībero-*. This seems to be the analysis that would be adopted by Cser 2016, who refers to the masculine nominative singular *piger* as being built on a stem *pigr-*, with no stem-final vowel (p. 129), despite the use of [ō] in the ablative singular form *pigrō.*
3. Draconis's answer indicates that "stem" has been used in some sources to refer to a different concept that is similar to what the other two approaches would call the "root" or "base" of a noun. I'm not sure which specific sources use that definition. It might have lasted longer in pedagogical contexts than in linguistic texts.

### Heteroclisy in more detail

One clear example of a heteroclite Latin noun is *vās*: the ablative singular *vāse* is built on the stem *vās-,* while the genitive plural *vāsōrum* is built on the stem *vāso-.* (Historically, the explanation in this case is that the different stem is derived from a "collateral" form of the noun; [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvas2) says that in anteclassical Latin, *vāsum* existed as a separate nominative singular form. But in Classical Latin, the stems *vās-* and *vāsō-* came to be used in complementary contexts, which allows *vāse* and *vāsōrum* to be analyzed as forms of a single noun. I've generally seen this noun described as having the stem *vās-* in the singular and *vāso-* in the plural, although the nominative/accusative plural *vāsa* is formally ambiguous: it would look the same regardless of whether it represented *vās-* + *-a* or *vāso-* + *-a*).

A number of other Latin nouns may or may not be analyzed as "heteroclite" depending on how you think of the idea of a "stem". This issue came up in a discussion I had with Joonas Ilmavirta beneath the answer that he posted to the question *[What consonants can a noun stem end in?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/9212/9)* Many third-declension nouns show an *i* in the genitive plural (before the ending *-um*) but not in most of the other forms (e.g. *vermis* has the genitive plural *vermium,* which seems to be built on the stem *vermi-,* but the accusative *vermem* and the ablative *verme,* which seem to be built on the stem *verm-*).

#### The stems of nominative singular forms

The situation gets even more complicated if you try to include nominative singular forms in your analysis; for this reason, I've seen a number of pedagogical texts that don't attempt to relate the nominative singular form to a stem, but that just present the nominative singular as a form that must be memorized as a whole. Nonetheless, from an etymological and possibly even from a synchronic perspective, almost all Latin nominative singular forms can in fact be analyzed as being composed of a stem and a suffix.

According to the theories that use definitions 1 or 2 of the term "stem", Latin has a nominative singular suffix with a fairly small number of variant forms or allomorphs: mainly -s, -∅, and -m. (Cser 2016 lists one additional allomorph, *-ēs,* to account for certain third-declension nouns (p. 127)). The form of this suffix is conditioned morphologically by the gender of the noun, and conditioned phonologically by the form of the end of the noun's stem (for example, nouns with a stem ending in a consistently take -∅).

Note that I did not include *-r* in my list of forms of the nominative singular suffix. As far as I know, Latin has no words ending in *-er* that would be analyzed as having a stem ending in *-e.* If you're familiar with that fact, you can determine that *līber* does not have the stem *lībe.*

For some words, the stem of nominative singular can be analyzed as being the same in an "underlying" way as the stem of the other forms, even though it appears different on the "surface". For example, the nominative singular form *rēx* be seen as being built synchronically on the same stem *rēg-* as the other forms of this noun. The explanation is that *rēg-* + *-s* becomes *rēx* according to known rules for combining Latin sounds: g turns into k before s.

I remember encountering theories that take a different approach to explaining variant phonetic forms like this (I forget where, and which language was being discussed): we could say instead that the stem of the noun *rēx* is "stored with" two allomorphs, **rēg** and **rēk**, and that there are rules that take these two allomorphs as an input and select the appropriate allomorph (rather than taking **rēg** as an input and turning its **g** into a **k**). This is a bit of a hairsplitting distinction in most contexts, however. Cser 2016 says that the "rule-based" framework adopted in that dissertation is simply for convenience.

### The "stem" (def 1 or 2) is viewed as including the "theme vowel"

According to definitions 1 or 2, the "stem" of a noun includes the "theme vowel"/"thematic vowel". For example, *servus* is an "o-stem" noun, so the stem would end in o: *servo-*. (If I remember correctly, from an etymological perspective, I think only second-declension nouns have stems that end in a PIE "theme vowel"; the first-declension *a*-stem nouns and fourth-declension *u*-stem nouns come from PIE forms that ended in a consonant that was vocalized in the history of Latin). Allen and Greenough's grammar, which seems to use a very etymology-based definition of "stem", says that *servus* has the "base" *serv-* and the "stem" *servo-* ([27a](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/roots-stems-and-bases)).

The form we get when we truncate the vowel (*serv-*) would be called the "root".

According to definition 2, Latin stems in this sense do show some allomorphy: for example, in the nominative singular form of *servus* we find [servu] (with short *u*) rather than [servo]. This is explainable in terms of diachronic sound changes, but the correct synchronic analysis isn't necessarily the same as the diachronic explanation. The stem vowel may (appear to) disappear entirely in some forms, such as the ablative/dative plural *servīs.* One possible synchronic analysis (given by Cser 2016) is that *servīs* is divisible into a vowel-final stem *servo-* and a vowel-initial suffix *-īs,* with a morphophonological process of vowel deletion resulting in the lack of [o] or [ō] in the surface form *servīs.* If I remember correctly, the historical development is a bit different: I think that the *ī* in forms like this comes from earlier diphthongs *oi* (or for a-stem nouns, *ai*), which were weakened outside of the first syllable to *ei,* which later monophthongized to [ī].

A similar analysis is often used in the linguistic analysis of Romance languages, the modern descendants of Latin. You can see an overview of this approach applied to Spanish in Bermudez-Otero 2012.

#### Sources

Cser, András. 2016. "[Aspects of the phonology and morphology of Classical Latin](http://real-d.mtak.hu/896/7/dc_1106_15_doktori_mu.pdf)".

Bermudez-Otero, Ricardo. 2012.  "[The Spanish lexicon stores stems with theme vowels, not roots with inflectional class features](https://ling.auf.net/lingbuzz/002773)".

Comment: maybe you want to read some articles about PIE root?

Comment: @zzzgoo: I have a basic familiarity with the concept of PIE roots. But I have the impression that Latin inflection shows significant differences from what is reconstructed for PIE.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the question meant stem to be the thing where inflection endings are added. That is the practical approach adapted by many pedagogical texts, but need not have anything to do with how the various forms actually came to be.

Comment: An excellent answer as always. In Greek, neuter words on *-os* also get an *-e-* in declined forms instead of the *-o-*, as with *genos* "race, breed, sex" : nom. *genos*, gen. *gene-os → genous*, dat. *gene-i*, nom. pl. *gene-a → genê*. Greek *-o-* most probably corresponds with Latin *-u-* here. Could it be e/o Ablaut? // Also interesting are cases where the stem remains the same but the gender changes, as with *locus*, pl. *loci* and *loca* collaterally.

Comment: @Cerberus The analogy with Greek goes even further: _gene-os_ is originally _gene-s-os_, but intervocalic sigma in Greek usually vanishes. And Latin _gene-r-is_ is the result of rhotacism, where intervocalic s becomes r.

Comment: @sgf: Indeed! I can never remember when it's intervocalic h and when intervocalic s, in Greek. I believe the latter normally turned into the former before disappearing?

Comment: @Cerberos I only remember initial s -> h, usually before e (whence _hemi_ for Latin _semi_) (and maybe _Helios_ for _Sol_?), but I wouldn't know how we could tell that s had turned into h between vowels, since Greek had no way for writing h between vowels.

Comment: @sgf: https://i.imgur.com/8I16D6E.png Voilà! From here: https://books.google.com/books?id=BwHPKIUXKGsC&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=greek+medial+h&source=bl&ots=qlLs_VWXUs&sig=ACfU3U17yiqnSS72RwoxLT8RZA2Ua-AJ7w&hl=en&sa=X#v=onepage&q=greek%20medial%20h&f=false

Comment: Did a consonant get vocalized to make the alpha-stems? I thought the ending was `*-eh₂`, where the laryngeal just colored a pre-existing vowel.

Comment: @Draconis: I was just referring to the loss of the laryngeal consonant (with compensatory lengthening) as a form of vocalization.

Comment: @sumelic Ahh, I see. Fair!

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: "the thing where inflection endings are added" is still ambiguous unless you have a clear definition of what Latin's inflectional endings are. Does the nominative singular have an inflectional ending, and if so, does it take forms like *-s, -∅, -m* or forms like *-us, -a, -um*?

Comment: @sumelic True, it is ambiguous. I should have been more precise and said something closer to "the thing that stays immutable across inflection", with some exceptions like the singular nominative. To me the stems of *pars*, *genus*, *amare*, and *facere* are *part-*, *gener-*, *am-*, and *fac-*. Occasionally one might want to define a stem by analogy, so that for example in second conjugation the stem of *rubere* is *rub-* analogously to the other conjuations. From a pedagogical point of view stems like this seem to work well.