# How can you find the stem for an adjective in Latin?

Tags: adjective

For example, for the word *bonus, bona, bonum* ('good') the masculine nominative singular obviously has the same stem as the oblique forms. But, with a word like 'our' (*noster, nostra, nostrum*) how can you identify the stem with which to decline the word?

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks! The answers here are very useful!

Comment: @ermatveit I'll second that welcome. I hope you stick around and ask more Latin questions. Make sure, when you're ready, to accept the answer which answers your question best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are exceptions to the rule, but like nouns you can often predict what the stem is from the genitive declension of the adjective.

With your example, the genitive singular endings of *noster, nostra, nostrum* are

> nostri -i (m)

> nostrae -ae (f)

> nostrum -i (n)

If you drop the *-i* or *-ae* ending, you'll get *nostr* as the stem. For third-declension adjectives, drop the *-is* ending.

For more information, see this question about [how to find the stem of a noun](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/10561/how-to-find-the-stem-of-any-word/10563#10563).

Comment: While what you say is certainly true, one needn't look any further than the adjective's principal parts (that is, the dictionary entry) to make the same determination – it's sort of the point (or one of the points, anyway) of having principal parts. For 1st/2nd declension adjectives, the feminine and neuter nominative forms tell the stem: thus libera and liberum indicate that the e is part of the stem of that adjective, whereas pulchra and pulchrum indicate that the e isn't part of the stem. The situation is a bit more complex for 3rd declension adjectives, but the principle is the same.

Comment: @cnread Yeah, I would say it doesn't work for 3rd decl. adjective. The feminine and neuter of *sapiens* is *sapiens*, but the stem is *sapient-*. The genitive is safer for those.

Comment: @cmw, Yes, but in cases like sapiens, most dictionaries I know will give the genitive singular as the second principal part. So that's what I meant by the principle's being the same: the principal parts are all you need.

Comment: @cnread Ah, I see what you mean now. Got it.

Answer (score 4):

An adjective almost always uses only one stem for its entire declension, excluding degrees. The genitive singular of any gender will tell you that stem. Just be careful about [UNUS NAUTA adjective, or one of the *naughty nine*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMFcKMmSM7E). They have genitives in -ius and datives in -i, but otherwise are normal.

Here are some examples:

The 1st/2nd declension adjective *ruber, rubra, rubrum* has genitives *rubri, rubrae, rubri*. The stem is very much *rubr-*.

the 3rd declension adjective *vetus* has genitive *veteris* for all genders. The stem is *veter-*.

*Neuter, neutra, neutrum*, an UNUS NAUTA adjective, has the genitive *neutrius* for all genders. Since we know that -ius is its genitive, we can say that the stem is *neutr-*.

Once you get used to the way adjectives tend to decline, you probably won't need to look at the genitive for every adjective.

I'd check out Allen and Greenough's Latin Grammar for more, like [this section](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/3rd-declension-adjectives-classification-and-paradigms) on 3rd declension adjectives. This section is more to give you an understanding of the possibilities, even if it doesn't always go into the reasons very much. I very much recommend it, since most people would not find it helpful to understand why the system is the way it is.